# Style sheet CSS: table cell dimension and padding

Tags: html, css, joomla, css-tables

I don't know CSS, I'm working with Joomla using a template; I need a formatted table in my page with some information.
I found this table sheet that seems good for my purpose:

```
<style type="text/css">
/*syllabus*/


table {
width: 10%;
    //margin-right: auto;
    //margin-left: auto;
    text-align: left;
    //border-collapse: collapse;
    //border-bottom: 5px solid;
    //border: 20px solid #fff;
    border-color: 993333;
    //border-spacing: 0.0;
    //box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 7px #999999;
    padding: 0px;
}


td {
  //padding-left:   10px;
 // padding-top:    10px;
  //padding-bottom: 10px;
 // padding-right:  10px;
    padding: 0px;
}

table a
{
    color: #CF7600;
    padding: 0px;
}

thead {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #fff;
}

thead > tr {
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 0px;
}


//#CFCFCF
tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f7f7f7;    padding: 0px;}
tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #ECECEC;    padding: 0px;}


tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
}
</style>
```

but I can't remove this kind of "padding" in my rows:
[image: padding between text and table]

all the `padding` field in the code are my test to resolve the problem (without success).
How can I remove this orrible space between text and table?
It seems to be also that I can't resize my table  (`table {
width: 10%;` has no effect)...Maybe, is there another global CSS that "hide" my local CSS? How can I disable it in my page?

Comment: Use [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) there you can easily test your css, with a tooltips.

Comment: @volperossa  try this css  " table table > *{  padding:0;} "

Comment: Also, if you could show how your HTML is structured, that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a cell in the table contains a lot of data and it automatically go to newline destroying my layout;
I resolve my problem with

```
max-width:100%;
white-space:nowrap;
```